# Function to sum group based on id independently based off id

Tags: sas, sum

i am currently trying to write some code that goes through my dataset and sums each group everytime it appears independently of the whole group. this is what it currently looks like vs what i want it to. I thought it would be simple but sas 9.3 does not support sum over statements/

```
    week       ID  var2 ... MinUnits group 
    24jun2019  1    x       5        0          
    01jul2019  1    x       4        1          
    08jul2019  1    x       7        1          
    15jul2019  1    x       2        1
    22jul2019  1    x       0        2          
    29jul2019  1    x       5        2 
    05aug2019  1    x       2        2     
    24jun2019  1    x       9        0          
    01jul2019  2    x       5        1          
    08jul2019  2    x       6        1
    15jul2019  2    x       8        1
    22jul2019  2    x       1        2          
    29jul2019  2    x       5        2
    05aug2019  3    x       3        2
```

what i want it to show

```
 week       ID  var2 ... MinUnits group  SumMinUnits
    24jun2019  1    x       5        0          5
    01jul2019  1    x       4        1          13
    08jul2019  1    x       7        1          
    15jul2019  1    x       2        1
    22jul2019  1    x       0        2          7
    29jul2019  1    x       5        2 
    05aug2019  1    x       2        2     
    24jun2019  1    x       9        0          9
    01jul2019  2    x       5        1          19
    08jul2019  2    x       6        1
    15jul2019  2    x       8        1
    22jul2019  2    x       1        2          9
    29jul2019  2    x       5        2
    05aug2019  2    x       3        2
```

as you can see simply summing by group would not work because the group number gets repeated for different ID's (and eventually same ID's but in those cases a location variable is different than the orignal time the ID showed up).

please note i am not asking for you to code it for me as that is too much work. i just want to know if there is a functin i could use to do this. I thought about using a loop and groupby but that would sum up the total groups

Comment: Normally when you summarize you reduce the number of records.  So since you have 6 groups you would output only 6 observations.  Having the extra observations is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NOTSORTED keyword on the BY statement use the GROUP variable to make BY groups.

```
data want;
do until (last.group);
  set have ;
  by group notsorted;
  SumMinUnits=sum(SumMinUnits,MinUnits);
end;
do until (last.group);
  set have ;
  by group notsorted;
  output;
end;
run;
```

Note this will set SUMMINUNITS to the same value for all observations in the group.  You could add extra code to set it to missing inside the second DO loop when it is not the first observation for the group.

Comment: Smart, thanks for all your help. It worked perfectly. The NOTSORTED Keyword seems like it can be a very useful tool to me in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work? It adds the total to every record of the group but otherwise your data seems order by ID and GROUP.

```
   proc sql;
   create table want as
   select *, sum(minUnits) as total_units
   from have
   group by ID, GROUP;
   quit;
```

Comment: this one ended up adding all the mins for each ID which is the problem i kept running into myself. However, Tom's suggestion worked if you are interested in seeing how it was solved.